# Excel mapping with string comparison

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to Excel VBA.
I am having following excels.
I have the following pieces of data.

Following is the master table

### Master

```
item 1  |   k1,k2,k3
------------------------
item 2  |    k1,k2
------------------------
item 3  |      k3
------------------------
```

following is the items table

### item

```
    1   item 1
----------------
    2   item 2
----------------
    3   item 3
----------------
```

following is the keywords table

### keywords

```
10  k1
-------
11  k2
-------
12  k3
-------
```

i would like to obtain following excel as mapping of item and keyword based on master table.

```
1   10
-------
1   11
-------
1   12
-------
2   10
-------
2   11
-------
3   12
-------
```

Can anyone plz help me
Thanks in advance.
I am new to excel vba and macros

Comment: By tables, do you mean worksheets ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't feel like your question is very clear, but if I understand your question correctly, you should be able to accomplish this just using vLookup, no need for VBA/macros. If you can't figure it out from there, please clarify your question.

[Vlookup Tutorial](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php)

Comment: tried excel vba looping.Worked fine.Thanks for help